# In SQL 2005/2008 management studio, how to I get the 'summary' tab to be visible?

Tags: sql-server, settings, ssms

In SQL 2005/2008 management studio, how to I get the 'summary' tab to be visible?

I close it by mistake and want to open it again...any way without restarting it?

Comment: Can you please register yourself? You have 3 accounts, and your reputation should be consolidated.

Comment: It shouldn't be, becauase I haven't registered as an open ID slave!

Comment: Yeah. and you are chock full of irritating questions. How many do you get closed or downvoted? Its an irritation to the community.

Comment: Stingy, a few have been correct, but far from an irritation as I'm sure some of my questions help others.  sorry jack.

Comment: Have some integrity and join the community. Unless you want to be hidden because you are up to no good....

Comment: Stingy, I am participating so I have 'joined' haven't I?  When the site allows for non-registered members to participate, and if I don't care much about points why bother?  What does integrity have to do with it??/

Comment: Stingy, out of the 50+ questions I must have asked on this site (probably over 100), like 2-3 were fun questions.  Have some balance in your 'attacks'...."chock full"??

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2005 Management Studio:
View Menu -> Summary (or F7)

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio:
View Menu -> Object Explorer Details (or F7)

Answer (score 0):

Window Menu --> Reset Window Layout

Though its more or less a useless window. The object explorer is much more useful.

Comment: That's true for the most part, but you can't select multiple objects there.

Comment: It would be nice if it could default to columns/parameters view